# Como funciona o Flash Messages no ZF 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Estou trabalhando com o [**Zend Framework 2.0**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html) e reparei que ele tem um helper para tratar mensagens de erro, chamado "flashMessages", o que não entendi direto é se ele captura isso por sessão, ou pela renderização da view, estou quebrando a cabeça para usar esse helper, alguém sabe me dizer como poderia implementar isso num formulário?

Aqui está meu método:

```
public function userDataAction() {

        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Service\FrmUserData');
        $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url()->fromRoute('user-admin', array('action' => 'persist-user')));

        $session = new Container('Admin\Service\FrmSearchUser');

        if (isset($session->data)) {

            $em = $this->getEm();
            $repository = $em->getRepository('Base\Model\Entity\Entities\Document');

            $document = $repository->findOneBy(
                    array(
                        'value' => $session->data['document_cpf'],
                        'type' => 'cpf'
                    )
            );

            if ($document instanceof \Base\Model\Entity\Entities\Document) {
                $user = $repository->searchUserById($document->getUser()->getIdUser());
                $repositoryUser = $this->getEm()->getRepository('Base\Model\Entity\Entities\User');

                $data = $repositoryUser->corrigiCampos($user);
            }
            $form->setData($data);
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);
        }
          $messages = null;
        if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()) {
          /* aqui eu gostaria de setar as mensagens
           de saída como poderia fazer isso? */
           $messages = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();
        }

        return new ViewModel(
                array(
                  'form' => $form,
                  'title' => 'Consultar / cadastrar usuário',
                  'subTitle' => 'Preencha os dados abaixo',
                  'messages' => $messages
                )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **Plugin FlashMessenger**, manda a sua mensagem para um pool de espera (Através do **FlashMessenger Plugin MVC** do Zend) que será exibido em outra requisição de página (Através da **ViewHelper FlashMessenger**).

Você está errando em enviar a variável para a **View**, veja abaixo como funciona.

Existem 4 tipos de mensagens que você pode integrar com os **Notifications do Bootstrap (error, info, default, success).**

**Agora vamos a prática**

Na sua **Action** dentro da **Controller**, você precisa informar a mensagem e seu tipo:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger;

public function registerAction(){
  if($formValid){
      $this->flashMessenger()->addSucessMessage('Registro Salvo!');
  } else{
      $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Erro ao Salvar');
  }

  //redireciona para outra rota e só depois exibe
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('app');
}
```

Na **View**  (.phtml), você só precisa usar:

```
#exibe mensagens do método addErrorMessage();
echo $flash->render('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-danger'));
#exibe mensagens do método addInfoMessage();
echo $flash->render('info',    array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-info'));
#exibe mensagens do método addMessage();
echo $flash->render('default', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-warning'));
#exibe mensagens do método addSucessMessage();
echo $flash->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success'));
```

Na **View**, se tiver usando **Bootstrap**:

```
 $flash = $this->flashMessenger();
 $flash->setMessageOpenFormat('<div>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
         &times;
     </button>
     <ul><li>')
     ->setMessageSeparatorString('</li><li>')
     ->setMessageCloseString('</li></ul></div>');


 echo $flash->render('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-danger'));
 echo $flash->render('info',    array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-info'));
 echo $flash->render('default', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-warning'));
 echo $flash->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success'));
```

Agora vai um **Hack**, se você deseja exibir os **FlashMessages** logo na tela sem a requisição (Ideal para erros de formulários, no qual você não redireciona ou **AJAX** para outra página), use o renderCurrent, e não esqueça de limpar.

```
echo $flash->renderCurrent('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-danger'));
```

Caso queira se aprofundar melhor no assunto, segue os links da documentação Oficial Zend 2, dá uma experimentada nos métodos disponíveis, vai ajudar bastante:

**VIEW** -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html

**CONTROLLER** -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger